# В чем разница между результатами выполнения программ на С++ и Python

Tags: c++, python

В чем подвох и почему выдает разные результаты? 
На **Питоне** проходит только **75%** верных ответов.
К тому же, не могу понять, что не так с двумя последними тестами.

[Вот задача.](https://www.e-olymp.com/uk/problems/2)

> **Вычислить количество цифр целого неотрицательного числа `n`.**
>
> *Входные данные:*
>
> **Одно целое неотрицательное число `n (0 ≤ n ≤ 2 ∙109)`.**
>
> *Выходные данные:*
>
> **Количество цифр в числе `n`.**

**С++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char a[10];
    cin >> a;
    cout << strlen(a);
    return 0;
}
```

**Python**

```
s = input()
print(len(s))
```

> И в С++, и в Python функция возвращает тот же результат - длину
>   строки.

Comment: Добавьте задачу в вопрос.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, есть ссылка.

Comment: ссылка может стать недействительной и это понизит ценность вопроса

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. Если результаты равны, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Питон не знаю, но, судя по описанию...

Ведь `input` - он пробелы тоже берет? А то ведь если ввести пару пробелов, 34576 и штук 10 пробелов - то C++ только число и возьмет, пробелы выбросит.

Ощущение, что дело именно в этом.

P.S. Именно -

```
s = input()
print(len(s.strip()))
```

проходит на 100%...

Comment: А если примитивно: 
`s = input()
count = 0
i = 0
while s[i]==' ':
    count += 1
    i += 1
print(len(s)-count)
`

Comment: Ваше дело :) Я Питон, еще раз, не знаю. О том, как пробелы убрать, узнал только несколько минут назад из Интернета...